# How to scroll above top?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

In sublime 3 there is setting scroll_past_end - cool thing, how about scroll_past_top, scroll_above_top?

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible - there is an open feature request for this here:
https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1270

Also, [there is no event fired when a view is scrolled](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/api-suggestions/20640/46?u=kingkeith), so writing a plugin to do this isn't possible.